# Odometer execution on div scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to solve this problem, but i'm really bad when it comes to javascript ...

I am trying to load the odometer function on scroll (just after the Lorem Ipsum Text). Actually, when you load the page, the counter is already running, and i'd like to trigger it when on div load.

```
setTimeout(function(){
odometerOne.innerHTML = 456;
odometerbis.innerHTML = 2009;
}, 1000);
```

Can anyone enlight me on this ? Please, some help would be much appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/ok7mwLqu/

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Perhaps [**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/goka80n7/) ?